# Qt application with FMOD audio library crashes on launch on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, fmod

I made an example that works on desktop when I build it to EXE but crashes when I run APK on smartphone. I use 2.02.16 API version, JDK 17, NDK 22, Qt 6.2.4, and Redmi 4x (Android 7)

Settings:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/fmod-2.2.16/inc

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH, armeabi-v7a)
{
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += $$PWD/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libfmod.so
}

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    widget.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    assets.qrc
```

APK is created after 1-2 minutes without problems. This is a source code of my example:

widget.h

```cpp
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <fmod.h>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:
    FMOD_SYSTEM *m_pSystem;
    FMOD_SOUND *m_pSound;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```cpp
#include "widget.h"
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QFile>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    FMOD_System_Create(&m_pSystem, FMOD_VERSION);
    FMOD_System_Init(m_pSystem, 32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

    QString soundPath(":/assets/audio/music.wav");
    QFile f(soundPath);
    if (!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Faild to open the file: " << soundPath;
        return;
    }
    QByteArray soundData = f.readAll();

    FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO* exinfo = new FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO();
    exinfo->length = static_cast<unsigned int>(soundData.length());
    exinfo->cbsize = sizeof(FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO);
    FMOD_System_CreateSound(m_pSystem, soundData.data(), FMOD_OPENMEMORY, exinfo, &m_pSound);

    FMOD_Sound_SetMode(m_pSound, FMOD_LOOP_OFF);

    FMOD_System_PlaySound(m_pSystem, m_pSound, 0, false, 0);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "widget.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I use `armeabi-v7a` to build a release:

[image: ![image|419x133](upload://pQbknE9tF5IHq1aSRs1qrmiqecl.png)]

I tried without FMOD and it runs on smartphone without problems. But my example above crashes with this report (scroll to the end of the first post on the following link): https://qa.fmod.com/t/qt-application-with-fmod-crashes-on-launch-on-android/20561

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn’t find class “org.fmod.AudioDevice". You did not include the FMOD SDK in your APK. [Quick documentation link](https://www.fmod.com/docs/2.01/api/platforms-android.html#java)

Comment: I read it before, but I think that it is for Java developers only. I asked about it in the topic on the official FMOD forum: https://qa.fmod.com/t/qt-application-with-fmod-audio-library-crashes-on-launch-on-android/20561/2

Comment: First sentence under the heading I linked to: "FMOD is primarily a native C/C++ library implementation but does have a Java component that is invoked from native code. "

Comment: Thank you very much! I will study this docs https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/deployment-android.html step by step, I will study how to include "fmod.jar" and maybe later I will solve this problem. But now for a while I will use QMediaPlayer even for 3D domes. I built an example with Bullet Physics for Android (included it with source like I made with Box2D). I want to focus on porting my RE1 demo from pure WebGL 1.0 to Qt Android OpenGL ES 2.0: https://8observer8.github.io/webgl10-js/room-webgl-js/

Comment: I just wanted to find analog for Web Audio API for Qt Android that supports 3D sound. I tried OpenAL-Soft, FMOD, Bass Audio Library and SoLoud. But I haven't been able to play any of them on Android yet. Maybe later I can do it.